# Templatizing function using comprehension

Tags: elixir, metaprogramming

Assume we have the following implementation:

```
defmodule SomeModule do
  @celcius_coefficient 800
  @rheinan_coefficient 900
  @fahrenheit_coefficient 1000

  @available_units [:celcius, :rheinan, :fahrenheit]

  def foo(some_struct) do
    some_var = get_var(some_struct, :var_name)

    if some_var == :kelvin do
      initialize(some_struct)
    else
      bar(some_struct, some_var)
    end
  end

  defp bar(struct, :celcius) do
    mult(struct, @celcius_coefficient)
  end
  defp bar(struct, :rheinan) do
    mult(struct, @rheinan_coefficient)
  end
  defp bar(struct, :fahrenheit) do
    mult(struct, @fahrenheit_coefficient)
  end
end
```

There are module attributes starting with `*_coefficient`, where `*` is a keyword indicating something. We're implementing a `bar/2` to match all of the available clauses. The implementation is cumbersome, when we need to add a new unit, we need to implement a new function to match the new unit, which is going to be evaluated by the same expression.

[An implementation in Comeonin library](https://github.com/riverrun/comeonin/blob/master/lib/comeonin/base.ex) uses comprehension for generating functions for all clauses. I suggested the following approach:

```
defmodule SomeModule do
  @celcius_coefficient 800
  @rheinan_coefficient 900
  @fahrenheit_coefficient 1000

  @available_units [:celcius, :rheinan, :fahrenheit]

  def foo(some_struct) do
    some_var = get_var(some_struct, :var_name)

    if some_var == :kelvin do
      initialize(some_struct)
    else
      bar(some_struct, some_var)
    end
  end

  for unit <- @available_units do
    defp bar(struct, unquote(unit)) do
      coefficient = unquote(Module.get_attribute(__MODULE__, :"#{Atom.to_string(unquote(unit))}_coefficient"))

      mult(struct, coefficient)
    end
  end
end
```

The module attribute should be retrieved using `Module.get_attribute/2` during compile time, since it will not be available in runtime.
We also need to unquote the `unit` parameter, to supply the proper atom to the function.

It throws a compilation error, saying: `unquote called outside quote`.
Having tried to put `quote` clauses in some places, nothing helped.

I guess I'm having some misunderstandings and confusions about metaprogramming in Elixir.

Do you have any suggestions?

I'm also in a dilemma about using `defp` or `defmacrop` to define `bar/2`. What would be the correct construct for doing such kind of thing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the unquote around the inner `unit` value since it's already unquoted:

```
coefficient = unquote(
  Module.get_attribute(__MODULE__, :"#{Atom.to_string(unit)}_coefficient")
)
```

Program:

```
defmodule SomeModule do
  @celcius_coefficient 800
  @rheinan_coefficient 900
  @fahrenheit_coefficient 1000

  @available_units [:celcius, :rheinan, :fahrenheit]

  for unit <- @available_units do
    def bar(struct, unquote(unit)) do
      coefficient = unquote(Module.get_attribute(__MODULE__, :"#{Atom.to_string(unit)}_coefficient"))
      {struct, coefficient}
    end
  end
end

IO.inspect SomeModule.bar(1, :celcius)
IO.inspect SomeModule.bar(2, :fahrenheit)
```

Output:

```
{1, 800}
{2, 1000}
```

(I made the function public for testing, you can make it private again if you don't want to use it outside this module)

> I'm also in a dilemma about using defp or defmacrop to define bar/2. What would be the correct construct for doing such kind of thing?

Only define a macro when you need to use the function as a macro. In this case, you don't need that, so `defp` (or `def`) is fine.